# Postgresql or psql 'rails db' password error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to prompt the psql interface to try to create a database, actually following from Dr. Hartl's tutorials http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2.

I created the project with:

```
rails new postgr_ --database=postgresql
```

I added passwords to the database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: postgr__development
  pool: 5
  username: postgr_
  password: 12345

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: postgr__test
  pool: 5
  username: postgr_
  password: 12345

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: postgr__production
  pool: 5
  username: postgr_
  password: 12345
```

I then enter into terminal:

```
$ rails db
```

And I get the following error after entering my password:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgr_"
```

I've been going at this a good part of yesterday and all day today and was unable to work around this. I may very well be missing something fundamental, if you spot it please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `postgr_` using inside PostgreSQL?

Comment: postgr_ is the project name and username. I do not know where or what file to look.

Comment: @mu is too short: does the pgadmin app for PostgreSQL need to be modded to run? any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I don't use pgadmin.

Comment: is there any method you would suggest i try? So far it seems i either can't enter the correct password or run into the `psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?` error

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the steps to setup the postgresql role and database creation.

This procedure depends on the system you are using. I will assume that you are using a mainstream linux distribution.
First login to the postgresql account. You may use one of the following commands:

```
$ su - postgres
```

or

```
$ sudo -i -u postgres
```

Once logged in, start the psql program:

```
$ psql template1
```

At the psql prompt, create a new user role and a database for your project:

```
=> create role postgr_ with createdb login password '12345';
```

Then simply quit the program

```
=> \q
```

And logout from the postgresql user account

```
$ exit
```

Then you should be able to run the `rail db` command successfully

Comment: Thank you. I go to:

    $ sudo postgres

receive: 

    "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.

and for the su command, get:

    su: Sorry

Comment: Do you have local administrator priviledges on this machine?

Comment: absolutely, sorry for the delay. The error also states 'The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.'

Comment: @aug2uag The `sudo` command was wrong; `sudo postgres` will try to run the command `postgres` (which is the PostgreSQL server back-end) as root. You want `sudo -u postgres -i` for an interactive login as user `postgres`, or you want `sudo -u postgres psql template` to just run `psql` directly as user `postgres`. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: at the GNU prompt I entered with and without sudo '=> create role postgr_ with createdb login password '12345';' and received in both cases '-bash: create: Permission denied'. It's probably something I need to find the solution somewhere. I'm crossing my finger that the above will work.

Comment: the '=>' symbol indicate the prompt of the psql program, not something you must write to the shell prompt.

Comment: @aug2uag That makes very little sense. As didierc notes, `=>` is the usual non-superuser prompt for the `psql` interactive shell, but that error message is from bash not psql. Bash usually has a `$ ` or `# ` (the latter for root) prompt. When you run `sudo -u postgres psql template1` you should get a `template1=#` prompt you can type the `create role` command at. Are you on Mac OS X? In that case, depending on how you installed PostgreSQL you might need to use the user named `_postgres` (note leading underscore) instead, or use `psql -U postgres template1` without sudo.

Comment: you are absolutely right. i jumped the gun.

in bash I entered `psql template1` and received:

`psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Does 'user' in database.yml file have to match user on shell?

Comment: I installed using Homebrew on OSX 10.7 and there is the RVM in there also. I get the error `postgres is not in the sudoers file` with `sudo -u postgres psql template1`, and the error above with `psql -U postgres template1`. Thank you.

Comment: @aug2uag: In my explanations, each command must be successful for the next to run correctly. So if you could not execute the sudo command, then you cannot expect the psql command to succeed either.

Comment: @didierc: i think this project is too much over my head at the moment. the book even says it is for 'advanced users' so maybe some better luck in the future. thanks for your feedback, suggestions, and help!

Comment: sorry, I don't know how I can provide a better help.

Comment: you and others have been very helpful! thank you for your time and care (: